# Is loading bytecode in Luajit script slower than loading strings?

Tags: lua, luajit

The problem:

I have been testing two types of large files (roughly 20MB).

The first is a string file with around 4000 functions in it like:

```
function dostuff1()
    <simple lua script>
end

function dostuff2()
    <simple lua script>
end
```

And so on.
The functions themselves are not overly important, but each one has very specific important simple operations in them.

The second file is simply a bytecode built version of the text file using:

```
luajit -b testfile1.lua testfile1.out
```

Then I test each file (load times) for each of them into their own env using:

```
local env = {}
local chunk = loadfile( filename, 'bt', env )
assert(pcall(chunk()))
```

The string files are significantly faster to load and process than the bytecode files. Which seems counter to what I would expect. Heres a small sample of comparisions. Note: some files have more complex functions in them than others (hence the time differences).

String files:

```
'#  File Load+Run: '    'test.tbl1'     '  Time: '      0.72784 '   Size:'      20877534
'#  File Load+Run: '    'test.tbl2'     '  Time: '      0.686193        '   Size:'      20880495
'#  File Load+Run: '    'test.tbl3'     '  Time: '      1.109813        '   Size:'      20824589
'#  File Load+Run: '    'test.tbl4'     '  Time: '      1.582231        '   Size:'      20827788
```

Bytecode files:

```
'#  File Load+Run: '    'test.out1'     '  Time: '      0.379144        '   Size:'      17521943
'#  File Load+Run: '    'test.out2'     '  Time: '      0.95122 '   Size:'      17519371
'#  File Load+Run: '    'test.out3'     '  Time: '      2.954594        '   Size:'      18333035
'#  File Load+Run: '    'test.out4'     '  Time: '      7.236041        '   Size:'      18327247
```

Oddly the first file is faster in bytecode (which is what I expected for all of them).

Can this be clearly explained? I have searched in many places (here specifically) and could not find any similar discussions (let me know if there are - please).

Comment: Have you tried comparing the times with the GC turned off `collectgarbage("stop")`?

Comment: Need the GC on due to other portions of the system sadly, so it would be hard to test that. Might see if I can extract and test it. 
From what we are seeing. It looks like extra operations are occuring when the bytecode is parsed. Begun examining some other Lua bytecode compilers and similar and most of them operate on the C side of lua, not the script side.